# Want’s to Marshall different set of POJO fields based on Spring Profile

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, profile

I have a POJO **Deatils** having following fields.
    1. String Name
    2. String Add
    3. String Phone
. 
For profile ‘x’ first two fields should marshal in XML and for other profile first and last field should marshal in XML.
Note: no field will be null for any profile.

Comment: Why don't you add a marshaller that will look at the spring profile and do the marshaling?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it would be better to leave the Marshaller alone. It may be tricky to extend and customize the marshaller to fit your needs per Spring profile.

If our goal is to serialize different payloads depending on Spring profile, I'd recommend maybe a converter/factory that takes in the POJO (that has all the fields) and spits out a Data Transfer Object (DTO) for the specific profile.

Perhaps the following could work unless there is another end-goal in mind.

```java
public class Details { ... }
```

```java
// essentially a marker interface
public interface MyDto {
}

public class DtoA implements MyDto {
   private String name;
   private String add;
}

public class DtoB implements MyDto {
   private String name;
   private String phone;
}
```

```java
public interface DtoConverter {
   MyDto convert(Details details);
}

public class DtoConverterA implements DtoConverter { ... }
public class DtoConverterB implements DtoConverter { ... }
```

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
   @Bean
   @Profile("a")
   public DtoConverter dtoConverterA() {
       return new DtoConverterA();
   }

   @Bean
   @Profile("b")
   public DtoConverter dtoConverterB() {
      return new DtoConverterB();
   }
}
```